AWS Rekognition - how to use multiple manifests
I have a model that will need more classes with time, so I will begin with just one manifest file created with Ground Truth with a single class and new iterations will needs to add to the dataset a new class/images.
How can I add new manifests to the dataset ?
the purpose is increasing the dataset for the specific project with time
